# Buildfire: Auth onLogin method not working

Tags: buildfire

I am looking to integrate the buildfire auth for onLogin method.

I created a custom plugin and in the settings tab i checked the 'Require Login' checkbox. That way, now when i open this plugin in app it navigates me to the login page.

I now need to get the information right after user log in into the app. For this, in the wiget index.html file i added below script, which should do a callback as stated in the documentation.

Here is my code, which calls my external url and create a log there.

```
buildfire.auth.onLogin(function(err, profile){
    $.ajax({
        url: MY_URL_HERE,
        data: {'user': profile},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            //response
        }
    });
});
```

This code is not seem to be working. However other methods in the Auth are working for me. Can someone please let me know what i am missing here?

Also, is there any method similar to this for registration as well? like OnRegister or something. Please let me know other possibilities.

Thank you.

Comment: Here is the documentation for Auth https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-auth

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by it's not working? Are you getting an error in the callback, it the callback not triggering, etc?

Comment: onLogin is an event handler it doesnt invoke Login. You would need buildfire.auth.login to invoke it.

Comment: @Daniel_Madain I want event handler, not login check.

Comment: @attila226 I am not getting any error. It just doesn't work. My code inside the handler is not running. Callback is not working. At which event my ajax code will run?

Comment: Basically i want to call ajax and run my code whenever any user login into the app. So it like a hook, right after user login run the code. Just one time.

Comment: OMG!! Daniel was correct. buildfire.auth.login worked for me!. Don't know how, but i just tried with that and in the callback my function is now executing. :)